# spring boot with aws secrets manager is not download the secrets

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have updated the Spring boot from 2.0.9.RELEASE to 2.4.3, and I am using the package to get the AWS Secrets version 2.2.5.RELEASE. When I deploy the code, it looks like it didn't find the credentials, and the database connection can't be closed.

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=myapp
aws.secretsmanager.region=eu-central-1
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 2.4.0 Bootstrap phase was deprecated, that is why nothing is happening.
Because of deprecation and giving users more control over specifying which secrets they want, a new way of loading secrets was introduced in 2.3.0.
More about the new way and prefered way of loading secrets with spring.config.import can be found on [here](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.0-RC2/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager).

However, if you would still like to use old way of loading secrets with bootstrap phase, please add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>{spring-cloud-version}</version>
</dependency>
```